# Verilog signed vs unsigned samples and first

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, hdl

Assuming I have a register `reg [15:0] my_reg`, which contains a 16-bit **signed** sample:

How do I convert the sample from signed to unsigned? 
I have read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), and am aware of the 2-bit complement for signed numbers, but how do I perform this conversion in Verilog efficiently?
(I don't know if `my_reg` is positive or negatve, and it changes in every clock cycle = I receive a new sample on every positive clock edge).

The ultimate goal (to add a little bit of context) is to implement a digital FPGA built-in automatic gain control (AGC).

**EDIT:** as suggested I have split the two questions in two different posts. See the other one [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166295/verilog-bit-change-location)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the absolute value of my_reg?  That's different than converting from signed to unsigned.  E.g. if my_reg = -154 do you want my_reg_unsigned to be +154?

Comment: @Russell : not exactly, as I want to be able to difference positive and negative values. I think absolute value will not help. Say I have values from -10 to 10, I just want to map them to 0 to 20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Verilog a reg contains binary data, signed unsigned are just a matter of interpretation. The bit values stay the same, subtraction and addition are always performed using two's complement.

For example, we can look at a 4 bit value and see how the numbers can be interpreted:

```
  Binary Unsigned  signed  
  1000          8      -8
  1110         14      -2
  1111         15      -1    
  0001          1       1
  0010          2       2
  0111          7       7
```

I think you want to calibrate these numbers on to a positive scale, -8 becomes 0, 0 becomes 8, 7 becomes 15. This would be done by **adding 1 in to the MSB position**. In our 4 bit example:

```
  Binary   Signed  Addition Unsigned result
  1000         -8  +1000    0000   0
  1110         -2  +1000    0110   6
  1111         -1  +1000    0111   7
  0001          1  +1000    1001   9
  0010          2  +1000    1010   10  
  0111          7  +1000    1111   15
```

There are some closely related questions:
1. [Verilog: how to take the absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511498/97073).
2. [Verilog Construction of Two's Complement Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21900424/97073).

If your register really does contain signed information then semantically you should define it as :

```
reg signed [15:0] my_reg;
```

To absolute the value:

```
reg signed [15:0] my_reg;
reg        [15:0] my_reg_unsigned;

always @* begin
  if (my_reg < 16'd0) begin
    my_reg_unsigned = -my_reg ;
  end
  else begin
    my_reg_unsigned = my_reg ;
  end
end
```

If you do not need to absolute it but just want to use that number to drive some thing it is valid to just connect signed to an unsigned, ie:

```
always @* begin
  my_reg_unsigned = my_reg ;
end
```

This will copy the bit values, `my_reg_unsigned` can be interpreted as signed using `$signed(my_reg_unsigned)`

Comment: Thanks. Which operators synthesize to different logic based on the signed-ness of their operands? Certainly `< <= >= >` come to mind. You already said addition and subtraction stay the same. What about multipliers? And is unary `-` even allowed on unsigned wires/registers?

Comment: @Tobia +, - all work naturally on unsigned and signed numbers. unary ~ performs a bit wise invert (ones complement) , ie does not care about sign. Unary - performs a twos complement invert +1, it does not care about the signed ness of input. The only functions that come to mind are comparaisons > >= <= < multiplication and divide