# Verilog bit change location

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, bit

Assuming I have a register `reg [15:0] my_reg`, which contains a 16-bit **signed** sample:

How can I find the place where the first bit change is located?
Meaning, that if assuming that `my_reg = 16'b0001011011010111`, how can I know that the first change from `0` to `1` is at `my_reg [12]`? Same for numbers starting with `1`,negative numbers, e.g. `my_reg = 16'b1111011011010111` would be interested in the position of the first appearing `0` (which is `11` in this case).

The ultimate goal (to add a little bit of context) is to implement a digital FPGA built-in automatic gain control (AGC).

Comment: When you say `"(which is 5 in this case)"`, do you mean bit number `11`?

Comment: @Ari : yes, sorry I got that mixed up. The change would be at `my_reg[11]`, thus place 11 (as you pointed out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same technique as described above but parametrized.  Use XOR shifted by one bit to determine where bits change, then use a descending priority encoder to output the first
change location.  I stuffed with `my_reg[0]` so the first bit doesn't create a delta.

```
localparam width=16;

reg  [width-1:0] my_reg;
wire [width:0] delta;
reg  [$clog2(width)-1:0] index; // Note: $clog2 was added in IEEE1364-2005
integer i;

assign delta = my_reg ^ { my_reg, my_reg[0] };

always @* begin
  index = 0;
  for (i=0; i<width; i=i+1)
    if (delta[i])
      index = i;
end
```

Above code on EDA playground (thanks for heads up on this, BTW)
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3uP

Comment: Pretty good for a first answer. I converted it from SystemVerilog to Verilog to match with the question's requirements.

Comment: @Greg : thanks for the answer! One question: shouldn't the foor-loop be reversed (meaning for(i=0;i<=width-1;i++))? In your implementation I would get the smallest index where there is a bit change. Or am I seeing something wrong?

Comment: @titus.andronicus, The answer came from Guy. And yes, you want to reverse to loop. I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, I assumed by first you mean the lsb.  Yes if you want the first msb change you need to reverse the loop.

Answer (score 2):

A two-liner solution for this is the following:

```
my_reg1_diff = (my_reg1 ^ (my_reg1 << 1))>>1 ;
my_reg1_diff_pos = $floor($ln(my_reg1_diff)/$ln(2));    //log2 of (my_reg1_diff)
```

See a working example on [edaplayground.com](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2yk).

It is similar to the idea described in starbox's answer. You can model a synthesizable `log2` function using a look-up table or case statement. See [edaplayground.com](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2yk) for a sample.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a leading signs detector.

You can do this by performing an XOR of the 16-bit my_reg variable, then a case statement that will count the number of repeating bits, then you need to add one to this number.

For example:

if we have a four bit register, we can count the number of leading bits.  You can modify this code for your purposes depending on how you want to handle what happens if all the bits are identical.

```
wire [3:0] my_reg;
wire [2:0] xor_bits;
reg [2:0] count;

// XOR bits
assign xor_bits = {my_reg[3] ^ my_reg[2], my_reg[2] ^ my_reg[1], my_reg[1] ^ my_reg[0];

always @ (*) begin
case (xor_bits)
000: change_location= 4;
00X: change_location= 3;
0XX: change_location= 2;
default: change_location= 1;
endcase

end
```