# Iterating over bits in FPGA

Tags: algorithm, vhdl, verilog, fpga

Now I'm trying to figure out best method for iterating over bits in FPGA. I'm using some variation of fast powering algorithm, a.k.a exponentiation by squaring (more precisely it's doubling and add algorithm for elliptic curve mathematics). To implement it on hardware, I know I must use FSM which does iteration. My problem is how to properly "handle" moving from bit to bit. My first thought was to switch order of bytes, but when my k = 17 is 32bit, I must discard first 27 bits, so it's rather stupid idea. Another concept was with "moving" 0001000 pattern and bitwise & it with number, but it also requires to find first nonzero bit.

TL&DR
Got for example k = 17 (32bits, so: 17x0 10001) and want to iterate 5 times (that means I start iteration on first "real" bit of number) knowing each bit I iterate over.

Language doesn't matter - I need only the algorithm, not solution in specific language. However, if it is easily done in Verilog, I wouldn't mind. :P

Comment: With a little googling you can find a bunch of papers using the search term "doubling and add algorithm elliptic curve VHDL" and optionally throwing in FSM.  You'd be hard pressed not being able to find a description of the algorithm. A data dependency graph is a close to abstract as a block diagram.

Comment: Yeah, but almost all algorithms describe loop from "l-1 to 0", and completely don't know how to get bits count l of number. I guess logarithm is rather bad idea. :P

Comment: You can always iterate 32 times and ignore 27 results.

Comment: Yes, but this would result in 27 wasted cycles - and that's why I'm asking here. To learn something new and better! :)

Comment: Check out this question on finding the first non-zero bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166295/verilog-bit-change-location/24169188#24169188

Comment: In your TL-DR example, the second two-digit number may be meant to be a _27_. `start iteration on first "real" bit` is that to say from the most significant bit? Do you need to know its position/weight? If the number isn't zero, that bit will be one… and the first iteration should give ample time to figure out the bits to follow/the position/weight of the leading 1-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Don not code for FPGA but still:

1. rewrite algorithm to iterate number x from LSB to MSB
2. then in each iteration bit shift x right by 1 bit
3. stop if x==0.

this way you have bit-scan inside your main loop and do not need additional cycles for it.

- x!=0 is done easily by ORing all its bits together

C++ code example:

```
DWORD x = ...;
for (; x != 0; x >>= 1) 
{
    //here is your iteration loop stuff like:
    if (DWORD(x & 1) !=0 ) ...;   
}
```

Comment: @Martin Thompson what does added space after bullet number mean in markdown? (do not take this the wrong way I just want to know the difference so I use it right in the future)

Comment: It turns it into a "real" numbered list (where the browser formats it as an <li>), rather than one done "by hand".  You can even put the same number on each line and the browsers numbering will carry on (see latest edit :)

Answer (score 0):

A dedicated combinatorial circuit to find the first nonzero bit, shift it to the first position and tell you the shift amount should be fairly light on resources.

In principle, the compiler should be able to find this solution on its own and improve on it:

```
if none of the top 16 bits are set, set bit 4 of the shift amount, and shift by 16.
if none of the top 8 bits are set, set bit 3 of the shift amount, and shift by 8.
...
```

The compiler should be able to find further optimizations on this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
always @ *
casex(num)
    8XXX_XXXX: k = 32;
    4XXX_XXXX: k = 31;
    2XXX_XXXX: k = 30;
    ...
```

Should give you the value of k.

You can have a shift register which can be parallel loaded so you can write a 1 to the kth bit, so you know when your iterations have ended.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop from 0 to 31 and discard the 27 leading zeros...you aren't necessarily wasting cycles.  Depends on whether you've surrounded this with a synchronous process, or a asynchronous one.

One gives you a rather small clocked circuit with a 32 clock latency.
The other gives you a giant rats nest of ANDs and ORs which won't run at a very high frequency.

Depends on what you want.  Remember though, that even if you do decide to loop over 32 clocks, you can PIPELINE it such that you start a new calculation every clock.  It might take you 32 clocks to get an answer, but you CAN do them at high speed.